# JS - Handle initial server response to display JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am working on a webpage. I am doing the front end and my colleague is doing the back end and web-server. He's using golang to write the web-server. Right now, his handler for `'/'` requests (i.e., if I am hosting it locally, just plain localhost - not localhost/foo, etc.) is to send me back an html template/static file, which gets displayed automatically (I don't handle his template in any way with my JS).

We are now moving the webpage over to a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), and we have decided that he sends me the html to display using JSON. I am capable of handling JSON which comes from AJAX requests, which is how I display data on every other url request (using jQuery - `$.ajax().done()`, etc.); however, he still sends me a template to handle `'/'` requests, as I do not send an AJAX request for that.

The code that is currently being sent over as a template is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--head-stuff, this area is populated-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--body stuff, this area is populated-->
  </body>
</html>
```

> As we want to move fully over to sending JSON, the plan is that the web-server would send me JSON on `'/'` requests (i.e., the above template would be sent as JSON). I am trying to figure out how I would handle it (capture it - as it would be a response not connected to a request that "I" - i.e. my JS - invoked).

Is this even possible? Or would the initial send always have to be a static file/template (my Google searches have resulted in nothing).

Comment: If you want `/` to be the entry point into your application (some URL you can type into a web browser or a link you could follow), it needs to be HTML, or at the very least it can't be just JSON. JSON is just data, and a browser won't do anything with it unless you tell it what to do. So at the very least, you'll need a very basic HTML page and a bit of JS that will load the initial page delivered as JSON and do whatever magic is needed.

Comment: @jcaron tku. I updated my question to include the template currently being sent. So what you are telling me is that the above template would not be able to be sent in JSON, but would need to be a static file? Maybe my update clarified things more. Tku

Comment: You can send anything encapsulated in JSON. But the browser won't do anything with it spontaneously, whereas it will parse HTML, and most importantly for you, JS embedded or linked from that HTML.

Comment: @jcaron great thanks. Can you please post this as an answer, maybe with a link to any docs on the subject (so I can read up on them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need an address that you can enter into a browser or link to, it can't be just JSON.

JSON is just data, and a browser won't spontaneously do anything with it.

What you need is at least one HTML page (and most importantly in your case, the associated embedded or linked JS). The HTML page can be very basic and just load some JS (which could then load the rest of the JS, HTML, CSS, provided via JSON or other means), but it needs to exist, as it's one of the only ways to have the browser execute any code.